# What differs different Vulkan loaders from each other?

Tags: vulkan

First I wonder about some minor details to see if I understand some concepts properly:

- Is vulkan-1.dll (or libvulkan.so.1 on Linux) what is referred to as the loader?
- When I use `HMODULE vulkan_module = LoadLibrary( "vulkan-1.dll" );`, is this using the loader from the graphics driver (provided that the previous detail is true)?

Now to the actual question. It seems that the loader is responsible for pulling drivers together to have them seem as one "unit" of sorts, as well as collecting available extensions and validation layers. What then differs the LunarG loader (for example) from those provided by graphics drivers? Why would one want to use one over the other?

Comment: "`LoadLibrary( "vulkan-1.dll" )`" Any reason why you want to load that library manually, instead of using the import library?

Comment: I'm following a guide to get started with learning Vulkan and this is how the author chose to do it. Having learned programming using VS, any library requirements have more or less been taken care of automatically, so I'm not experienced with library importing in general. But that is a question in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Vulkan drivers do not contain anything that would reasonably be called a "loader". They are "providers".

The purpose of a "loader" is to load what the "providers" provide. The most basic thing a loader does is find the implementations' DLLs and interact with them. This differs based on the platform. With Windows, they probably use registry settings to hunt down the implementation DLLs. On Android, their built-in support probably centralizes things. And so forth.

The only commonly used loader is LunarG's SDK loader (which does use the filename `vulkan-1`). Some have written their own, but LunarG's is the only one with widespread usage.

Answer (score 0):

"the loader" or "official loader" or "Khronos loader" or "LunarG loader" or "VulkanRT" are AFAIK the same. It's from the project [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers).

What differs (between those provided by the Khronos, LunarG SDK, and drivers) is usually only a version. (Typically LunarG SDK lags behind Khronos and driver lags behind both.)

More then you ever wanted to know of its inner workings is in the [loader documentation](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/master/loader/LoaderAndLayerInterface.md).

Run-time dynamic linking as you propose should be possible (you would do the `LoadLibrary()` then `GetProcAddress()` the `vkGetInstanceProcAddr()` command and then rest from it).

(On Windows) I think most people use the convenient dll import library `vulkan-1.lib` from LnG SDK with whatever vulkan-1.dll is in the System32.